# Change Font Size and format

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Based on the code below, how can I change the font size and format?

For the size I tried:

Approach 1 (didn't work)

```
.text-large {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

Approach 2 (didn't work either)

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Code:

```css
a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-background {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1c2a48;
}

.logo,
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav .external-link {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-background container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/AgenciesAndServices/Pages/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/ReportAComplaint/Pages/Default.aspx">Report a Complaint</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspx">Terms of Use</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspxx">Accessiblity Statement</a></li>

        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://lp.constantcontactpages.com/su/ErJFVZz/BrowardLife">Subscribe</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://b.granicus.com/ViewPublisher.php?view_id=15">Watch Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx">Copyrights 2022, Government</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-white" style="padding-top: 3rem; text-align: center;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS selectors need to be more specific than Bootstrap's selectors . Also be sure you load your CSS after you load Bootstrap's CSS. And, `body { font-size: 16px; }` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap defaults to `16px` = `1rem`.  Given that information I added your two container classes to the CSS and made everything `2rem` with that specificity.

```css
.footer-background.container-fluid {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-background {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #1c2a48;
}

.logo,
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-pills {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav .external-link {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-background container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/AgenciesAndServices/Pages/Default.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/ReportAComplaint/Pages/Default.aspx">Report a Complaint</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspx">Terms of Use</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Terms/Pages/Default.aspxx">Accessiblity Statement</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://lp.constantcontactpages.com/su/ErJFVZz/BrowardLife">Subscribe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 center-block">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://b.granicus.com/ViewPublisher.php?view_id=15">Watch Meetings</a></li>
        <li><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/Pages/Welcome.aspx">Copyrights 2022, Government</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="text-white" style="padding-top: 3rem; text-align: center;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added these two classes to your css, and was able to change the font to Times New Roman, and increase the font-size. Add the class "test" to your li

```
<!-- add to your css -->
ul.nav-pills {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;} !important

.test {
 font-size: 24px;}

<!-- add class to yur li -->
<li class="test"><a class="external-link" href="https://www.b.org/opengovernment/prr/Pages/default.aspx">Public Records Request</a></li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/xefkmg20/3/